# Why am I getting ellipses in response to trying to insert an embedded document in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Here is my code on the mongo shell

```
db.products.insert({_id:3, name: "Rubber", price: 1.3,stock:43,reviews:[{authorName:"Sally", rating: 5 , review:"Best rubber ever!"}]})
```

Comment: And what exactly is the response from MongoDB?

Comment: The respinse is elipses. The three dots: "..." as opposed to the carat: >

Comment: That's probably because you have not completed the command. Are there any unbalanced opening quotes, brackets or parentheses?

Comment: Tested your exact command in a mongo terminal. Works great.

Comment: I don't get why it's not working in my shell... it just keeps repeating the ellipses..

Comment: I just pressed enter a lot and it turned out to work! Thank you.